# Angular Obervable undefined value

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create an observable method where I am returning a String value and subscribing it but I am not getting the returned String value after subcription.I am new to Angular

shared/ExamplenService.ts

```
    @Injectable()
    export class ExamplenService {
    someValue: any;



      public setSomething(){
      return  return Observable.create(observer => {
      cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: function (result) {
      this.sameValue=""// Extracting some value from  a http call
       });


    public getSomething(): any {
    const studentsObservable = new Observable(observer => {
       setTimeout(() => {
           observer.next(this.sameValue);
       }, 1000);
    });

    return studentsObservable;
   }
```

dashboard/test/TestComponent.ts

```
  export class TestComponent implements OnInit
 _data : any;


constructor(private http: Http, private example: ExamplenService) {

 }

  ngOnInit() {
   const s= this.example.getSomething().subscribe((_url :String)=>
   {
     this._data =_url;
     console.log("Rest1"+this._data);//This log is not showing in console
   });
   }
```

[image]

```
  console.log("Rest2"+this._data);This log is showing Rest2 Udefined
```

Comment: try with `getSomething() { return of(this.samValue).pipe(delay(1000)) }` ?

Comment: can you remove the `timeout` and try again

Comment: After timeout, I am not getting any error but I am still not able to get the this._data value. It still coming as undefined

Comment: console.log("Rest2"+this._data);This log is showing Rest2 Udefined

this is undefined as when it's executed, observable has been initialized, but hasn't executed any value yet (it will publish value 1 second later).

In template add <p>Data: {{ _data }} </p> this should print "hello" after 1s

Comment: @TomaszIz I have removed the time out and even after that both Rest1 and Rest2 values are showing as undefined..I am not using this value in Template. I am using on one of the components

Comment: this.samValue="hello" - this code is directly in class? this cannot work. Change it to:
someValue: any = "hello";

Comment: Actually, I am setting this value this.samValue on the other method of the same class.I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get `undefined` is because you never set the value. the function `setSomething()` is not called and hence you variable is never initialized.

i just added a demo along the same lines.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvbzfn

Comment: I am calling this function in one of the template    public setSomething(){
         return  return Observable.create(observer => {
this.sameValue="" // ectracting some value from http call
         });.. The problem is when I am setting this variable within the observable then It is not getting set as this.url. How do i store this value

Comment: i'm not sure if i understand the problem correctly!! Can you please update the above demo to help me understand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize 'this.samValue="hello"'.

```js
ngOnInit() {
this.example.setSomething(); // for initialisation
   const s= this.example.getSomething().subscribe((_url :String)=>
   {
     this._data =_url;
     console.log("Rest1"+this._data);//This log is not showing in console
   });
   }

  console.log("Rest2"+this._data);This log is showing Rest2 Udefined
```

Comment: I am setting that value on other methods. I have dited my question.

Comment: you need to call this method after calling "this.example.getSomething()"

Comment: I am setting this value on this method  public setSomething(){
     this.sameValue="hello"
     }

Comment: yes, but you need to call this method **setSomething()** to initialize the variable inside this method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193259/discussion-between-subham-and-saad).